# How to centralize repetitive Data placed in different SQL server databases?

Tags: sql-server

We have many applications in our organization that each one have its own database (mostly SQL server). There are some common data in most of databases, for example Employee data. How can we  make integration for such data?

Comment: The question isn't very precise, so I'll just give some points you may find interesting.

The simplest answer is to merge the databases into one. 
If databases are on different servers, you can create a database link [(see here)](http://dba010.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/how-to-create-database-link-in-sql-server-2005/) or create a Web Service for managing the common data.

Comment: There is a lot of thought and discussion on this. For some things to think about, but no practical solutions, look up Master Data Management. Compare MDM to what you're trying to achieve (but don't be led by it). Then improve your question with more detail. What is the *actual* business problem that prompts your question?

Comment: Its ok to use database link or web service, but how to make cascade delete or cascade update?(Is it possible to create relation between tables placed in different databases or servers?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too broad and there is no single solution for this. If you already have a lot of databases then just create another one that will hold all common data.

Just go ahead and identify all common data from all databases and have it stored in one place. Now, you’ll also have to mind the referenced tables and such which may lead to replacing all of your databases with just 2 or 3 new DBs that are bigger but it’s probably worth the effort in the long run.